# ToListAsync throws 'Value cannot be null.' Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

Having `IQueryable`

```
var query = _db
    .ApplicationPaidServices
    .Include(it => it.Application)
    .Include(it => it.Application.User)
    .Where(it => Enum1.Value1 == it.Application.Enum1)
    .Skip(0);
```

Executing *1*

```
 var result1 = await (from it in query
                      select it)
            .ToListAsync();
```

works.

Executing *2*

```
 var result2 = await (from it in query
                      select
                      new
                      { it })
                     .ToListAsync();
```

Throws `ArgumentNullException` with message : *Value cannot be null. Parameter name: arguments[2]*

stack trace

> System.Dynamic.Utils.ContractUtils.RequiresNotNull(object value, string paramName, int index)
>   System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.RequiresCanRead(Expression expression, string paramName, int idx)
>   System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, string methodParamName, string argumentParamName, int index)
>   System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateArgumentTypes(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, ref ReadOnlyCollection arguments, string methodParamName)
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable arguments)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.IncludeExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
>   System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)

**Commenting either `Where` or `Skip` on initial query fixes the error.**

Have no idea what's a reason.

*Using* `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` and `.NET Core 1.1`

Comment: Anytime you see such exception, be sure it's a current EF Core bug.

Comment: `.Skip(0)` ? - does skipping zero elements make sense? 
 https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/in-linq-beware-of-skip0-38313

Comment: @FredrikRedin This code is taken from real implementation of  paging, where argument of `Skip` function is not fixed number and is calculated based on current page number.

Answer (score 0):

Got bitten by this today. One possible workaround is to await `ToListAsync` before `Select()`:

```
        var paged = await queryable
            .OrderBy(m => m.Name)
            .Skip(0).Take(30)
            .ToListAsync();

        var result = paged.Select(ViewModel.Map).ToList();
```

Comment: Well, in this case, we lose the benefit of only loading `Select` part of the object from a database instead of a whole object.

Comment: Indeed. But when I wrote my answer, I was on EF Core 1.x, which retrieves the whole object anyway.